# How to delete specified directory in windows dos command

Tags: dos

In linux system, we use the follow command to delete the ".svn" directory in current directory and int its sub directorys.

```
find . -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Then, which command could we use to do the same function? 
thanks.

Comment: We just could use "rm -rf .svn" to delete .svn directory in current directory, but no in its sub directorys.

Answer (score 0):

you can try making a new batch file and writing the following code in it :

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d *svn') do (
  rd /s /q "%%i"
)
```

it will delete the .svn directory recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rmdir command at command prompt to delete the dir put  /s for subdirectories
Like:
rmdir c:\.svn /s

just start command prompt as administrator then execute this command.

For your reference:

Syntax:
rmdir [Drive:]Path [/s] [/q]
rd [Drive:]Path [/s] [/q]

Parameters
[Drive:]Path : Specifies the location and name of the directory that you want to delete.
/s : Removes the specified directory and all subdirectories including any files. Use /s to remove a tree.
/q : Runs rmdir in quiet mode. Deletes directories without confirmation.
/? : Displays help at the command prompt.

Refer this page for more detail: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rmdir.mspx?mfr=true